# How to properly do feature selection with SelectFromModel from scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

I am using a [very simple kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/breast-cancer-wisconsin-data) to understand how SelectFromModel with a logistic regression works. The idea was to create a very simple pipeline with some basic data processing (dropping a column + scaling), pass it to feature selection (logreg) and then fit an xgboost model (not included in the code). By reading the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html), my understanding is that given my X_train and y_train a logreg model is fitted and those features with coeffs higher or equal than the threshold are selected. In my case, I set the threshold to mean*1.25.

I cannot understand why the output `selector.threshold_` is not the same as `selector.estimator_.coef_.mean()*1.25.` I was expecting to get the same value, **why is it not the case?**

[image]

Moving forward, I wanted to do GridSearchCV to fine-tune my pipeline parameters. I usually do it this way:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

params = {}
params['gradientboostingclassifier__learning_rate'] = [0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
params['selectfrommodel__estimator__C'] = [0.1, 1, 10]
params['selectfrommodel__estimator__penalty']= ['l1', 'l2']
params['selectfrommodel__estimator__threshold']=['median', 'mean', '1.25*mean', '0.75*mean']

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, cv=5, scoring='recall')
%time grid.fit(X_train, y_train);
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the threshold is not in the list of parameters (`pipe.named_steps.selectfrommodel.estimator.get_params().keys()`) so for GridSearchCV to work this line needs to be commented.

```
params['selectfrommodel__estimator__threshold']=['median', 'mean', '1.25*mean', '0.75*mean']
```

**Is there a way to fine-tune the threshold?**

Answer (score 3):

Because the importance is based on the mean of the **absolute values** of the coefficients. If you do the mean on relative values, the average importance will be lower

I have built an example to demonstrate the behaviour:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X = [[ 0.87, -1.34,  0.31 ],
     [-2.79, -0.02, -0.85 ],
     [-1.34, -0.48, -2.55 ],
     [ 1.92,  1.48,  0.65 ]]
y = [0, 1, 0, 1]
selector = SelectFromModel(estimator=LogisticRegression(), threshold="1.25*mean").fit(X, y)
print(selector.estimator_.coef_)
print(selector.threshold_) # 0.6905659148858644
# note here the absolute transformation before the mean
print(abs(selector.estimator_.coef_).mean()*1.25) # 0.6905659148858644
```

Also note that the feature importance is a **consequence of your model training**, not something that you can define a priori. That's the reason because you cannot fit a threshold, which is obtained only after your training

Comment: Clear for the first part! What do you mean "consequence of your model training", you mean the logreg model, right? Can you further elaborate?

Comment: @G.Macia the model coefficients are obtained after the training, and only after that a threshold can be elaborated. You cannot select a set of thresholds before your training, because it is not an hyperparameter of your model. Don't forget to accept the best answer :)

Comment: the hyperparameters are usually defined before the training, not after.

Comment: @G.Macia to make it more clear, the coefficients are the result of your training given a set of hyperparameters (like for example the estimator penalty). You are not going to select your features during training

Answer (score 0):

`@Nikaido` question was totally correct for the first part and `abs()` was missing. This means that `abs(selector.estimator_.coef_).mean()*1.25` is equal to `selector.threshold_`

For the second part, it is indeed possible and the right way to do it is changing this line:

```
params['selectfrommodel__estimator__threshold']=['median', 'mean', '1.25*mean', '0.75*mean']
```

to this other line:

```
params['selectfrommodel__threshold']=['median', 'mean', '1.25*mean', '0.75*mean']
```

as `threshold` is a parameter from `selectfrommodel` and not from `estimator`, see below how to get the full list for both cases for further tuning of hyperparameters use these:

```
pipe.named_steps.selectfrommodel.get_params().keys() 
pipe.named_steps.selectfrommodel.estimator.get_params().keys()
```